# Is there any problem if I send more than 1000 mails from single laptop using different email ID's?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-api, gmail-imap

I am planning to send emails to different clients of different businesses using their respective mail IDs **using python script and Gmail API**. I am a little afraid that Google treats me as a span. Because I am sending emails to different clients using different mail IDs, but the IP address remains the same. I also make sure that there is some gap between the time of each two consecutive emails.

Do I need to worry about it?  Or Do I need to manually send Emails?

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be an issue if you keep the sending limits for Gmail, and the quota limits for the [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/quota).

Take in consideration that the limits for a Gmail.com account will be different to Google Workspace limits.

- **The limits for a free account are specified [here](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22839)**

> You may see this message if you send an email to a total of more than
> 500 recipients in a single email and or more than 500 emails sent in a
> day.
>
> When you get this error, you should be able to send emails again
> within 1 to 24 hours.

- **The limits for a Google Workspace paid account are specified [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852)**

> Maximum messages per day Daily sending limit per user account is 2,000
> 1,500 for multi-send,  and 500 for trial accounts.

You can use the following Google Documentation guide [here](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126) to prevent your emails to be mark as spam. In it, you will find some recommendations, and best practice to avoid been mark as a spammer.

Another reason you might be marked as spammer is base on user Feedback, you can read information about it in [this documentation](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6254652), and [here](https://workspace.google.com/blog/identity-and-security/an-overview-of-gmails-spam-filters).

> Simply put, to protect users at scale, we rely on machine learning
> powered by user feedback to catch spam and help us identify patterns
> in large data sets—making it easier to adapt quickly to ever-changing
> spam tactics. Gmail employs a number of AI-driven filters that
> determine what gets marked as spam. These filters look at a variety of
> signals, including characteristics of the IP address,
> domains/subdomains, whether bulk senders are authenticated, and user
> input. User feedback, such as when a user marks a certain email as
> spam or signals they want a sender’s emails in their inbox, is key to
> this filtering process, and our filters learn from user actions.